# Not able to run CTS on Windows

Tags: cts

when I run: java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp %JARS%(jar_files) com.android.cts.TestHost %CONFIG%(xml path) %* %DDCONFIG%
in cmd promt im getting following error, please anybody suggest solution for this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: and
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: and.  Program will exit.

Package com.android.cts.TestHost is exists in Jar file.which

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue by using cygwin

I found the solution on [this blog](http://yenliangl.blogspot.com/2011/05/run-android-cts.html)

You just have to do the modification of those two line in the script startcts :

```
JARS=`cygpath -w -p ${CTS_LIB}:${DDM_LIB}:${JUNIT_LIB}:${HOSTTEST_LIB}`
java ${JAVA_OPTS} -cp ${JARS} com.android.cts.TestHost `cygpath -w ${CONFIG}` "$@" ${DDCONFIG}
```

Then I was able to have the CTS prompt